# @GeneratedValue doesn't work. "java.sql.SQLException: Field 'ID' doesn't have a default value"

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, jpa, javabeans, persistence-unit

Context: `Jboss5.1`, `MySql 5.0`

I've tried a lot of possibilities .. a simple `@GeneratedValue` or other solution specifing explicitly the sequence generator, but also have the same problem...
There is the stack trace

```
22:00:53,334 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: insert into Lavoro (nome, userIDrichiedente, sede, stato) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
22:00:53,341 WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000
22:00:53,342 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] Field 'ID' doesn't have a default value
22:00:53,372 ERROR [[CreaLavoroServlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet CreaLavoroServlet threw exception
javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [org.swimv2.model.Lavoro]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.Ejb3TxPolicy.handleExceptionInOurTx(Ejb3TxPolicy.java:77)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:83)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:190)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:186)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer.dynamicInvoke(StatelessContainer.java:421)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invokeLocal(IsLocalInterceptor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.PojiProxy.invoke(PojiProxy.java:62)
    at $Proxy317.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:207)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:164)
    at $Proxy320.validaLavoro(Unknown Source)
    at org.swimv2.servlet.CreaLavoroServlet.doPost(CreaLavoroServlet.java:100)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [org.swimv2.model.Lavoro]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:614)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.jpa.tx.TransactionScopedEntityManager.persist(TransactionScopedEntityManager.java:187)
    at org.swimv2.controller.GestioneLavoro.validaLavoro(GestioneLavoro.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.java:69)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:73)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_1851190336.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_1851190336.java)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:88)
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_1851190336.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_1851190336.java)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:79)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [org.swimv2.model.Lavoro]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2186)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2666)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:645)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:619)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:623)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:220)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'ID' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
    ... 95 more
```

Actual entity code for the interesting part:

```
@Entity
public class Lavoro implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String nome;

    private String sede;

    private String stato;
```

Code in which I encounter the error:

```
Lavoro lavoro = new Lavoro();
        lavoro.setNome(formLavoro.getNome());
        lavoro.setSede(formLavoro.getSede());
        lavoro.setStato("PENDENTE");
        lavoro.setPersona(p);
        lavoro.setAbilitas(listaAbilita);
        lavoro.setRichiestapartecipazionelavoros(new ArrayList<Richiestapartecipazionelavoro>());
        lavoro.setPersonas(new ArrayList<Persona>());
        lavoro.setFeedbacks(new ArrayList<Feedback>());
        System.out.println("Prima del persist");
        manager.persist(lavoro);
```

NB:manager is the entity manager.

MySQL for the ID field is set to `NOT_NULL` and `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should check the mappings. There can be some problem with ID used in other table as a foreign key?

Comment: checked again! Resolved adding other individual 'id' to all entity linked... Not using anymore a foreign key.

Answer (score 7):

Are you using a sequence on MySQL? MySQL supports value generation usinf a AUTO_INCREMENT field on your database. You dont need to specify a SequenceGenerator.

Like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

MySQL field definition:

```
YOUR_FIELD BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Comment: Trying... Not working... i've putted '@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)' and I've setted AutoIncrement for the field in mysql... but the problem is still here

Comment: Thanks, it's work. but can I insert random id in a database? because I don't want auto increment an id.

Answer (score 3):

make sure that you are not using setter for your primary key in model class.
    package com.example.models;

```
@Entity
public class BlogDetails {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="B_Id",nullable=false)
private int b_Id;
@Column(name="EmailId")
private String emailId;
@Column(name="Title")
private String title;
@Column(name="BriefDetail")
private String briefDetail;
@Column(name="Detail")
private String detail;

public BlogDetails() {
}

public BlogDetails(String EmailId, String Title, String BriefDetail, String      

Detail) {
this.emailId=EmailId;
this.title=Title;
this.briefDetail=BriefDetail;
this.detail=Detail;
}

public int getB_Id() {
return b_Id;
}

public String getEmailId() {
return emailId;
}

public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
this.emailId = emailId;
}

public String getTitle() {
return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
this.title = title;
}

public String getBriefDetail() {
return briefDetail;
}

public void setBriefDetail(String briefDetail) {
this.briefDetail = briefDetail;
}

public String getDetail() {
return detail;
}

public void setDetail(String detail) {
this.detail = detail;
}


}
```

Comment: This throws an error: `org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter for property id in class `

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```